# How do I get a floating div to take up all available space

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="section">
    <p class="left">Some text</p>
    <div class="right">
        <p>item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5, item 6, item 7, item 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div.section {
    margin: 30px;

    background: blue;
}

div.section p.left {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: 4px;

    background: red;
}

div.right {
    float: right;
    word-wrap: break-word;

    background: green;
}
```

You can play with these in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JLJR/4/). It looks like this:

[image: Problem]

I would instead like it to look like this, wrapping the right-floated `<div>` to the width available without the "left" `<p>`:

[image: Desired solution]

How can I accomplish this (and please don't tell me Javascript, there should be a way to do this with CSS). I get the wrapping I want when I specify a width for the floating `<div>`, but I can't do that, since the width of the left `<p>` varies.

**Update**

Allow me to add a couple details. All the text is generated dynamically, and the width of the parent `<div>` changes. There may be 100 items, rather than 8. Splitting the `<p>` is not a workable solution.

Comment: `display:table;` is a must?

Comment: No, it is not, and I actually changed it to `display: inline;`. I didn't realize I had to update the Fiddle link, which I have now done.

Comment: The width of parent div varies? The width of `Some Text` varies? The width of the floated right div varies?

Comment: What I mean is that I can't hardcode a 10%/90% split or something like that. But the floating right `div` can grow to be longer than the left `p`. I want it to expand to use as much space as it can, without encroaching on the `p`.

Comment: When you shrink the size of the browser,when you make the browser smaller, which behavior do you expect?

Comment: The red box stays the same, the green box shrinks, and wraps to additional lines if necessary

Comment: This is exactly what Flexbox is designed for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes - however you will have to polyfill with JavaScript for some browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps

```
<div class="section">
    <p class="left">Some text</p>
    <div class="right">
        <p>item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5, item 6, item 7</p>
        <p>item 8</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Seems to work.

Comment: This is dynamic text. I'm giving you a placeholder. And the width changes, as well.

Comment: If you added that to the question it would help - i will now put the thinking cap on...

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left" style="float:left;width:10%">
Some Text
</div>
<div class="right" style="float:left; width:90%">
<p>item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, item 5, item 6, item 7</p>
<p>item 8</p>
</div>
<div style="clear:both">perhaps this without text if you want nothing else to float below</div>

</div>
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I can't decide the width in advance, since the width of "Some Text" changes.

Answer (score -1):

I tried it a little bit and I believe this is what you are looking for.
http://jsfiddle.net/2JLJR/4/

I gave the individual elements a float and a percentual width.

```
div#wrapper {
 margin: 30px;
 float:left;
 background: blue;
 height:auto;
}

p.left {
 display: block;
 width:20%;
 float:left;
 background: red;
}

div.right {
 float: right;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width:80%;
 background: green;
 text-align:justify;
}
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I can't decide the width in advance, since the width of "Some Text" changes.

Comment: So? persentual width is good for that. if the parent div has an automatic width.

Comment: No, it's not good for that. One instance may have a split of 10%-90%, the next may be 25%-75%, and I don't know in advance which it's going to be.

Comment: there is absolutely no certainty about the size of each field? You must have a general idea about it's size right?